# Rolling record of first time changes (& diffs) between two columns in a DF

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, time-series

My data is stored in a pandas dataframe.

Rule:

_Store the first value that appears in either col1 or col2. (Here it's df["col2"][0]).

_ Increment the row, if the next number appears in the same column, consecutively, ignore it.

_ The FIRST time a value appears in the alternate column take the difference...

_   Keep a rolling record of the values ONLY at the first col change, for both columns.

```
       Psedo-code e.g. based on sample data (plse see below): 


                df["new"][0]=df["col2"][0]-df["col1"][4]

                  Store df["col1"][4]

                df["new"][1]=df["col2"][9]-df["col1"][4]

                   Store df["col1"][9]

                df["new"][2]=df["col2"][9]-df["col1"][11]

                       etc
                       etc
                       etc
                        .
                        .
                        .


index    col1     col2

0                   46.84
1                   46.84
2                   46.84
3                   46.84
4       44.9501 
5       44.9731 
6       45.0229 
7       45.048  
8       45.0753 
9                 45.0753
10                45.0753
11     46.84
12     45.0229
13     44.9501
14     46.75
15     46.75
16     44.9731
17                 44.9501
18                 45.0229
19                 45.0229
20                 46.75
```

There are thousands of rows in the frame. Thoughts on the best way to do this are greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to my script:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5od59ejprwzu6ii/algo1.py

---

EDIT: user1827356 's suggestion in the comments section below.

---

```
 df['mapnl']= np.where(df['group']%2 == 0, df['result'], -df['result']) –
```

I tried the following line to fix this to try to negate every other value:

```
df['mapnl'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['result'] if row['group']%2 == 0 else -row['result'], axis=1)
```

It gives the same result as user1827356's suggestion.

Comment: Some combination of the ``shift`` and ``isnan`` methods should do it. (With ``dropna`` and ``diff``, ultimately.)

Comment: @DanAllan I linked to my script above that I tried fixing to no avail. The error is indent error. I don't see it. Do you see any glaring issues? Thanks, again.

Comment: Be consistent with your indentation. Four spaces is considered best practice. Your Row 39 looks like it does not match the indentation above it.

Answer (score 3):

This might be of help

```
df['col'] = np.where(df.col1.isnull(), 'col2', 'col1')

df['group'] = (df.col != df.col.shift(1)).astype('int').cumsum()

df['value'] = np.where(df.col1.isnull(), df['col2'], df['col1'])

df['first'] = df.value.groupby(df.group).transform(lambda s: s.iget(0))

df
       col1     col2   col  group    value    first
0       NaN  46.8400  col2      1  46.8400  46.8400
1       NaN  46.8400  col2      1  46.8400  46.8400
2       NaN  46.8400  col2      1  46.8400  46.8400
3       NaN  46.8400  col2      1  46.8400  46.8400
4   44.9501      NaN  col1      2  44.9501  44.9501
5   44.9731      NaN  col1      2  44.9731  44.9501
6   45.0229      NaN  col1      2  45.0229  44.9501
7   45.0480      NaN  col1      2  45.0480  44.9501
8   45.0753      NaN  col1      2  45.0753  44.9501
9       NaN  45.0753  col2      3  45.0753  45.0753
10      NaN  45.0753  col2      3  45.0753  45.0753

df['first'].diff(1).groupby(df.group).first()
group
1           NaN
2       -1.8899
3        0.1252
```

Comment: Nice answer. I suggest replacing ``.apply(lambda s: s.iget(0))`` with ``.first()``.

Comment: @user1827356 Thanks very much. I'll mark it as the answer as soon as I run it. 'where()' isn't working for me. I'm using windows, unfortunately so my upgrade fails, of course.  I don't know what error: unable to find vcvarsall.bat means. Probably something w/ an environment variable that I don't understand.

Comment: @DanAllan first() doesn't seem to work for me. user1374969 - I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the error

Comment: @user1827356 This is very elegant.  Only trouble is that this provides the "wrong sign" for every other value in df["first"]. Is there a way to change diff so that we are always subtracting FROM column 2?

Comment: For example, above should be row0-row4=1.8899 (positive number) then row9-row4=45.0753-44.9501=0.1252

Comment: Maybe you are using an older release on pandas. ``.first()`` is documented here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups

Comment: @user1374969 you can do result * np.resize([1,-1], df.group.max())

Comment: @DanAllan - I'm using pandas-0.10.0 and  pd.Series([1,2,3]).first() throws TypeError: first() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: first() is a method on group objects, not Series. Consult the documentation I linked for working examples.

Comment: I see the issue now. Updated answer. I wrongly thought you were referring to the iget used along with transform. Thanks

Comment: @user1827356 I run: df['result'] = df.value.groupby(df.group).transform(lambda s: s.iget(0)) then 

df['mapnl']=df['result']*np.resize([1,-1], df.group.max())

Comment: The error is ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5569) (69)

Comment: Did you mean something else?  I'm probably not understanding your parameters in resize np.resize([1,-1], df.group.max())

Comment: @user1374969 it seems like you want to multiply every other group by -1. If you are transforming the result you could try this df['mapnl']= np.where(df['group']%2 == 0, df['result'], -df['result'])

Comment: @user1827356 I upvoted your answer and posted an edit to my original comment above. But actually your suggestion df['mapnl']= np.where(df['group']%2 == 0, df['result'], -df['result'])  seems to negate the entire column of results instead of just every other value in the even numbered groups. Seems that it shouldn't though.

Comment: @user1374969 I'm unable to reproduce your issue. It seems to be fine when I run it. It might be useful to check the values of 'group', df['group']%2 and df['result'] to make sure they're as expected in terms of values and data type