# Invalid literal with base 10

Tags: python-2.7, casting, pandas

I have a df constructed from a csv below 'a' should be a double. If I check a?. It appears to be a string. In an attempt to convert it to an int(a), I receive a type error, 
I am not sure why.

```
   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '46.074'

  a=df["MA10"].ix[100]
   a=int(a) 


 Imported:
 df=pd.read_csv('__.csv',header=None,parse_dates=True, index_col={0},names="__".split())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use float

```
In [14]: int('46.074')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-f8e7b101e6bd> in <module>()
----> 1 int('46.074')

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '46.074'

In [15]: float('46.074')
Out[15]: 46.074
```

Comment: thanks. Think there something about the fact that I am using iterrows() which is turning this into a string? They are seen as doubles in the dataframe. I.E. I'm using

    for idx,row in df.iterrows()

Comment: show what your frame looks like after its read in and show a df.get_dtype_counts(). what is your end goal, what are you doing with iterrows?

Comment: I see float 4, object 10. My end goal is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019275/rolling-record-of-first-time-changes-diffs-between-two-columns-in-a-df

Comment: I link to my script there but I think maybe deque would be better for that goal....

Comment: check your data after read in, if there are non-numbers in a column that should be float, then it will be object and not work. you can try ``df.convert_object(convert_numeric=True)`` using 0.11.0rc1 to force convert to numeric (or set as NaN)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    int(float('46.074')//1)
```